# UITableView - How to Scroll header section along with table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have dynamic cell and dynamic header view for each section in uitableview. Ho de we enable the scroll for header along with tableview cell?

Comment: Could you be more precise, add code, screenshot, anything to help people here get what you want to do ?

Comment: Found the answer:- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;//Change as per your table header hight
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    }
} This above code will scroll the header view along with uitableviewcell or section detail view.

Comment: Thanks Ainu! My question was tableview dynamic header should scroll along with section detail (section cell).

Answer (score 30):

Change the table style to Grouped in xib.

Comment: Should add that in order for this solution to work for me, with a single group, I had to implement both `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.homeTableHeaderView;
}` and `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 64.0f;
}`

Comment: Nice! Never notice that before.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to show same UI approach for iOS 6 & 7 we have use the above in scrollview delegate.

Answer (score -2):

Add double the number of sections you actually have. Let even number of sections only have section headers, while odd number section should have only rows without section headers.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return double the number of sections.
return ([_arrSection count]*2);
}
```

and..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//Even Sections will have only header and no rows 
if(section%2 == 0)
    return 0;

//Number of rows return only is the section is expanded else return 0
return [arrRowsForSpecificSection count];
}
```

and...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//Odd sections will have no header
if(section%2 == 1)
    return 0;

//for even sections
return HEIGHT_FOR_SECTION_HEADER;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

//Odd section will have no header
if(section%2 == 1)
    return NULL;
//even section will have header
return Header_View;
}
```

Thus at run time it gives an impression that it is the header of current section that scrolls without getting fixed at the top. Smooth animation!!!! Cheers